# What is meaning of (*x++) in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
   int* x, y;
   base(int xx = 0, int yy = 0) {
      x = new int[4];
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)         
        x[i] = 1;   

      (*x++) = xx;
      y = yy++;
  }
  ~base() { delete[] x; }
};
class Derived :public base {
public:
    Derived(int xx, int yy) : base(xx), base1(yy) {
        cout << (*(this->x)) << " " << this->y << " " << (* 
    (base1.x)) << " " << base1.y << " ";
   }
   ~Derived() {}
private:
   base base1;
};
int main() {
   Derived objDev(32, 33);
   return 0;
}
```

I have problem with understand it.
Because i think it should give output as "33 0" but gave "1 0" and also i write in some std::cout for controlling in constructor body, and saw x[3] is -33686019 after '''(*x++) = x; ''' part. How could it be possible? how *x++ can change x[3] and why is this value?
and also compiler give error. doesn't *x++ mean what is x point, increase it? so when after assign xx to (*x++) wouldn't it be 32+1=33?
please help

Comment: That's why you hopefully have learned now, that definition of multiple variables in a single statements is bad.

Comment: You should edit the question to provide a [mre]. That means a **complete** program, not parts of the the code and descriptions of other parts. And you should show the exact complete output, not parts of it. That said `x++` modifies the value of `x`; it changes where `x` points. That changes the meaning of `x[3]`. You should be learning about pointers and this interaction between them and `x++` and `x[3]` in simpler code, not mixing it with a class definition that is added confusion.

Comment: FYI, `int * x, y;` is the same as `int * x; int y;`  The `*` *sticks* to the variable not the type.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: There is nowhere in the code shown that `y` is used as a pointer, and it is not involved in the questions asked in the text, so what makes you think OP has any confusion or concern about the type of `y`?

Comment: FYI, you have a memory leak.  You dynamically allocate memory for `x`, but never delete it.  I recommend using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since when has that stopped anyone from helpfully pointing out errors in comments?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, my comment is more of a reminder.  If somebody is at the level asking about (*++), they maybe making the mistake that they want two pointers, instead of one.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The code shown is a constructor. The destruction of the array (not `x`) would be in the destructor, not the destructor, so we do not see whether it is destroyed or not. (The destructor could reconstruct the necessary address from `x` even though it has been altered.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas: It was not helpful. It did not point out an error. It was just snide and bullying a student.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Only the OP can say whether it was helpful or not.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: No, that is not true.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There is nowhere in the code shown that `y` is used as a pointer, and it is not involved in the questions asked in the text, so what makes you think OP has any confusion or concern about the type of `y` or the definition of multiple variables?

Comment: @AyşenurTak: Nonetheless, both protocol on Stack Overflow and necessity require a [mre]. If you cannot post the exact code, you can reduce it and make changes or construct new code to illustrate the points you need to ask about. When you show fragments that leave out necessary definitions or describe code in ways that leave relevant questions unanswered, then readers cannot understand what you are asking. You must present a **complete** coherent question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: A reminder is “Remember that, to avoid a memory leak, the destructor needs to delete the object created by `new int [4]`.” “you have a memory leak” is not a reminder; it is an assertion of an error.

Comment: The asker is merely the first person to seek help from a question. There will be more, and the question needs to be helpful to them as well. If it's not understandable how an answer follows from the question,  the question and answer are not useful to them. It's like the old white board that has the first part of a proof, "It is inherently obvious from A that B...", and then the end of the proof. The tricky part almost always turns out to be the missing "Inherently obvious" bit in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

`x = new int[4];` creates an array of 4 `int` and sets `x` to point to the beginning of them. Because `x` is going to change, let’s call this array `A`, which will not change.

Then `x[0]` refers to the first element of this array, `x[1]` is the second, `x[2]` is the third, and `x[3]` is the fourth. So far `x[0]` and `A[0]` are the same thing, and so are the pairs `x[1]` and `A[1]`, `x[2]` and `A[2]`, and `x[3]` and `A[3]`.

`(*x++)` is grouped as `( * (x++) )`. `x++` does two things. It produces the value of `x`, and, as a side effect, it increments `x`. Since `x++` produces the value of `x`, `*(x++)` is the `int` that `x` points to before the increment.

This means that `(*x++) = xx;` stores `x` in the first element of the array, but it changes `x` to point to the second element, which is `A[1]`.

Once `x` points to the second element, then `x[0]` is `A[1]`, `x[1]` is `A[2]`, `x[2]` is `A[3]`, and `x[3]` is beyond the end of the array. `x[-1]` would be `A[0]`.

So, where the code sends `(*(this->x))` to `cout`, it is sending `A[1]`, which has 1 in it. That explains why you got output of “1”.

When you looked at `x[3]`, you were looking beyond the array. What is there could be some other value the program has worked with, completely unrelated to what is in the array. But accessing an element beyond array bounds can cause various problems with programs other than just giving a wrong value.

In the destructor, `delete[] x;` is wrong because `x` has been changed and no longer has the original address of the array. You could use `delete [] --x;` or `delete [] x-1;` to recalculate the original address. However, if a program has some need to use a pointer into the middle of an array, it is more common to store the base address and never change it and create a separate pointer into the middle. That is usually less error prone and easier for other programmers to follow.